# How to deal with "No TeX trees available; configure ‘TeX-tree-roots’" error?

Tags: latex, auctex, tex

When I open a new tex file and hit C-c C-e <RET> to create document environment, the message buffer shows

> TeX-search-files-by-type: No TeX trees available; configure ‘TeX-tree-roots’.

It will then exit the environment input procedure and there is no automatically created \begin{document} \end{document}. How do I deal with this problem? This has not happened before.

I am using an M1 MacBook Pro running macOS Monterey 12.0.1
Emacs version: 27.2
AUCTeX version: 13.0.14

Edit: The problem appears only when using GUI. Emacs in terminal works fine.

Comment: I cannot replicate this under linux: same emacs and AUCTeX versions.

Comment: I suspect Emacs doesn't find the program `kpsewhich`.  You can check that by inserting `(executable-find "kpsewhich")` in scratch buffer, putting the point after the `)` and hitting `C-x C-e`.

Comment: @ArashEsbati Thank you. You are right. Emacs GUI does not find kpsewhich. However, emacs in terminal is able to find it and there is no problem with creating a new environment. I will try to fix the path problem by myself.

Comment: @FranBurstall The problem is related to macOS. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the issue is, as @ArashEsbati suggested, that Emacs is not able to find `kpsewhich` in GUI. It is a macOS specific issue, as discussed in [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676826/making-the-path-and-other-environment-variables-available-in-emacs). We may set the environment PATH in GUI to be the same as in terminal by using the package [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell). With `use-package`, adding the following to my init file solved the problem.

```
(use-package exec-path-from-shell
  ;; Get environment variables such as $PATH from the shell
  :ensure t
  :config (when (memq window-system '(mac ns x))
        (exec-path-from-shell-initialize)))
```